# Should universities waste time giving PhDs to people that don't intend on "using" it?

Tags: phd

Considering how hard it is to get a PhD done due to limited resources, I was puzzled by reading about a guy in his 80s getting a doctorate. He made it clear that he has no intention to work so why would a university waste time on somebody like that?

The purpose of a PhD is to produce scientists capable of and motivated to make contributions to science. It is NOT to satisfy one's ego and pursue meaningless dreams.

Shouldn't the university instead educate someone who would actually use this degree?

https://6park.news/massachusetts/manfred-steiner-achieves-his-dream-of-becoming-a-physicist-at-89.html

Just to clarify: the age is irrelevant: if a 30-year-old said they want to collect a PhD as a trophy but never use it for practical needs then I think such a person should never get one, either.

Comment: Whats stopping me (24 years old) from getting a PHD and then not working in that field?

Comment: The question is loaded, if you wonder where the downvotes are coming from.

Comment: @Michael If you say that a PhD is a trophy you want to collect so you can brag about it but you don't have a PRACTICAL use for it, then the university should not give it to you. Age is irrelevant.

Comment: So me personally I think that someone with your attitude should never get a PhD. Ageism should be an automatical exclusion.

Comment: @Peter Dr. Steiner said "_I’m not looking for a paid job. I’m over that._" He did not say he will not use the knowledge obtained from physics PhD.

Comment: @Peter I am unsure what you would consider "using" a PhD - many people use such a title to obtain higher paying jobs (without doing any research after) - would you consider this a misuse of the PhD as well? In short: do you think  universities should only take on PhD students intending to pursue a scientific carreer?

Comment: @Sursule No, I would consider it a good use if it gives you employment opportunities.

Comment: It is an interesting question, especially if one refocus it on the country resources and not on the PhD candidate. It depends on many variables, that is sure.  Perhaps the example is unfortunate, but the question is reasonable. However, in my country the openings are so few that the problem does not even exist. Opposite, we have the problem of a public system educating students from primary school to master or PhD and a country not able to absorb them at the end, not in Academia nor in the industry.

Comment: Could you provide more context on your assertion concerning the *purpose* of the PhD. I reckon that for programmes, which are publicly funded, the *purpose* should broadly align with the wider funding objectives and may correspond to producing scientific outputs or some wider societal benefits. How about PhD programme funded or part-funded by private business? If a private company decides to fund a PhD programmes in hope of benefiting from potential discoveries who is there to stop them? I reckon that type of funding could come with some "strings" attached but that's a different conversation.

Answer (score 6):

It is not a waste of time. The PhD research itself has value, including presentations he might give about it, and in other ways.

The question is insulting to a person in his late 80s who has made a highly impressive achievement.

Comment: From personal knowledge, George Marsaglia did some excellent mathematical work when he was 86. Probably better than many in their twenties.

Comment: @gnasher729 in his late 80s he was a retired professor not a PhD student, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

I would not say that universities (or rather the people working there, and in this case supervisors and professors) waste time on PhDs. For them, supervising a PhD can be very little work, and in case of more theoretical research topics not very much ressources either (the books in the library are there no matter the number of PhD students). On the other hand, no matter what the PhD student intents on doing afterwards, the produced research will result in a higher scientific output and more publications - beneficial for profs and universities.

As long as those kind of PhD students don't take paid positions, scarce resources or scholarships away from others while doing their PhD (and I highly doubt that a retired doctor is requiring funding to to a PhD), and a professor has enough time on their hand to supervise, there is really nothing bad that comes out of it.